# poisson posterior = gamma function x uniform prior?

Tags: poisson-distribution, posterior

I was reading the section 3.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.02869.pdf). Above equation (3.2), the authors say

*"The posterior on the background estimate is then conservatively
taken to be the Poisson posterior using a uniform prior for a sideband ... "*

Then they show the equation
\begin{equation}
P(\mu_{BG}) = \Gamma(7N_{pass}/100+1.1/7)
\end{equation}
How could one possibly connect the Poisson posterior to a gamma function? The authors said that they used a uniform prior, and the posterior function is a Poisson distribution. Then is there a reason why the posterior equals to a Gamma function? I tried to explain this for an hour but couldn't.

In the equation $\mu_{BG}$ is the number of expected background events. ${N}_{pass}$  is defined in the paragraph above the equation 3.2. But I think the meaning of $N_{pass}$ is not important, since the point of my question is about the functional form.

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.  (Few people will try to answer if they need to read a paper first ...)

Comment: It seems like "sideband" is a parameter in the Bayesian specification that is not explicitly stated, but fed into the above model with the initial assumption that it is 7, so some of those "7"s should perhaps be $\psi$s and $\psi \sim $ Uniform.

Comment: Note this is a preprint, and the point of publishing these things is to solicit feedback from the community before seeking formal review. You should just message the corresponding author.

Comment: You might point out also that the paper frequently discusses "pseudoevents", "pseudo-events", and "psuedoevents" which are probably all the same thing and should be referred to consistently (and spell checked).

Answer (score 1):

You misread the equation, it actually states
$$P(\mu_{BG}) = \Gamma(7N_{pass}/100 + 1, 1/7),$$
with a "," instead of ".".

Indeed, it seems to the Gamma distribution with its two parameters, which is the conjugate prior distribution of a Poisson likelihood.

I do not understand the connection to the rest of the text in the paper, maybe someone with a better understanding of the subject may verify that the math display actually refers to a Gamma prior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that using uniform prior distribution (note that uniform distribution is a special case of Gamma distribution for $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 1$) will result in Gamma posterior when assuming the data comes from Poisson distribution, is that Gamma distribution is [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) to the Poisson distribution.

Using conjugate prior is convenient because you can be sure that no matter what the results of the experiment will be like, posterior distribution of the unknown parameter will be from the same distribution family as the prior distribution.

Comment: Sorry, “note that uniform distribution is a special case of Gamma” how can it be since they have different ranges?

Comment: The negative logarithm of a Uniform(0,1) variable is Gamma(1,1)

Comment: You can use inverse transform law to relate a uniform to *any* distribution function. The point is that for parameters to a Poisson density, the gamma is the conjugate prior - and a uniform doesn't factor into it at all.